# Javascript ECDSA get private and public keys?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ecdsa

All I need are to get a private and public keypair for ECDSA. Stanford Javascript Crypto Library does it in a non-standard way ( https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sjcl-discuss/UaWUyMWS3Rs ) and that's useless to me - like what's the point of making a MD5 library that gives different results to everything else?

Is there an actual, working way to use ECDSA in javascript?

Comment: Basically I would stay away from SJCL. Simple reason: multiple issues like this have been found - including very serious verification mistakes, and although Mike seems to know what he's talking about, the library is just not tested well enough for a cryptographic library to be used. I would seriously try to get around issues by using SSL (for browser based crypto) or a wrapper library (for "local" development). Note that I wrote a Java compatability library, so I would rather promote the software.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jsrsasign 4.0.0 now supports ECDSA signing and verification with EC private and public key.

http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/

I think this meets your needs.
Here is a demo page.

http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/sample-ecdsa.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the comment you link to talks about the format of the ECDSA signature, not the keypair. Secondly, it is a bit misleading:

The output from the ECDSA algorithm is two integers in the interval [1, n-1]. The ECDSA standard ([FIPS 183-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf)) does not specify way a standard method to encode this pair of numbers as a array of bytes.

One way is by encapsulating the numbers in an ASN.1 SEQUENCE. This is the way specified by [ANSI X9.62](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20X9.62:2005) and [RFC3278](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3278#section-8.2). It is the standard output from Java and (AFAIR) Microsoft CNG/.NET.

Another way is by left-padding the numbers with zeroes so they have the same byte-length as `n` and then just concatenating them. This is done by PKCS#11 and most smartcard implementations.

If I read the source code correctly, the SJCL encodes the ECDSA signature in the second way. You can easily convert this format to the first one.

Comment: Yes, it's an easy conversion from 2 binary octet strings to two **signed** integer wrapped in a relatively simple BER format (SEQUENCE with two INTEGER's). But please test it well, since these kind of conversions often **do** go wrong.